# External Bluray unit won't mount

Tags: usb, mount, 14.10

I have recently bought an ASUS SBW-06D2X-U external USB Bluray unit for my Dell Vostro 3350 i7 notebook. I pluged it as instructed, with an external power source, but the unit just flashes and never gets mounted.

The most strange thing is that I tried it on 2 computers at my work (12.04 and 14.04) and it worked flawlessly.

I used a USB voltage/amperage tester to check the ports and they have similar reads at my home and at work.

Checking dmesg I see that Ubuntu recognizes it and then immediately disconnects. When I first started looking for this issue I was using Ubuntu 14.04 64bits and in order to try to solve this I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.10 64bits but the problem continued.

Dmesg output: http://pastebin.com/1WWpPk8r

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:

result of 'lsusb -v -d 13fd:0940':

http://pastebin.com/KAc4VMxW

Comment: Do you have another CDROM/DVD, .. in that machine?  If yes, did the machines at work also have one?

Comment: Well, my home notebook has an internal ssd and a hdd. I have removed the original dvd writer and substituted it for a ssd. In my work the computers I tested are desktops and they both have dvd writers in them. Do you think this is relevant ?

Comment: apparently not...  ;)

Comment: Can you provide the output of `lsusb -v -d 13fd:0940` (you'll have to be fast to get some output, or be patient until you get output)

Comment: @Fabby, edited the post with the information you asked. :)

Comment: Weird... lsusb says Initio Corporation and dmesg says it's an Asus...  Did you install any non-repository drivers?  If yes, can you try removing them and try again?

Comment: The only non-repository driver I had was nvidia proprietary drivers (fglrx) I had downloaded from Nvidia site. They where compiled on my machine. Removed them. Installed Nouveau. Same thing. :(

Comment: I'm stumped...  Upvoted your question so it will get some more attention from people who know more then me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it work. It was an energy problem. I have a notebook "board" which serves as ventilation and usb hub. I pĺugged 2 usb hubs to it with keyboard and trackball attached to them and I was trying to connect the Blu-ray unit to one of the hubs. 
I disconnected all this, connect everything to an energized hub plugged directly to the notebook and it finally stabilized and mounted correctly.